# Display "X" when click on a Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

am extremely new to Tkinter library in Python. I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game using Tkinter library.

In my program, I just want to get an 'X' whenever I click on a box. However, every time I click on a random box, the X only shows up at the bottom right box. As shown here: [image]

Could you please help me fix my program so that I get an 'X' where ever I click on?

```
import tkinter as tk

def updateText():
    buttonText.set('X')


game = tk.Tk()
the_row = 0
the_col = 0


myBoard = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        buttonText = tk.StringVar()
        myBoard[i][j] = tk.Button(game, textvariable=buttonText, font=('normal',60), width=5, height=2, command=updateText).grid(row=the_row,column=the_col)
        the_col += 1
    the_row += 1
    the_col = 0

game.mainloop()
```

Comment: Here is the link where you can compile: https://repl.it/@aminator006/OverdueFragrantCodes#main.py

Comment: like @Mandera said. check my example out [tictactoe](https://github.com/MediaEU/TicTacToe/blob/master/tictactoe.py)

Comment: Apart from the issue mentioned in the answer of @Mandera, all items in `myBoard` will be `None` becasue they are the results of `grid()`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `buttonText` in your function is global, so it's always going to use the single latest one. The solution is to pass `buttonText` as an argument and also storing the unique `buttonText` obj.

Easiest way is to change your `command` argument to `command=lambda x=buttonText: updateText(x)` and then change your signature of `updateText` to `def updateText(buttonText):`